# How can I use abstract method with different parameters on classes?

Tags: java, oop, methods, abstract

How can I use an abstract method with Overriding on two classes.? But these two classes have the same method but different parameters. Is there any solution or should I make the method not abstract and type for each class differently?

```
public abstract int attack(Object object); // here is my abstract method from Character class



public int attack(Hero hero){ // this method from monster class
    int currentHeroHealth;
    int reducedDamage;
    System.out.println("You have been attacked by monster!");
    int attackDamage = getAttackDamage();
    int attackSpeed = getAttackSpeed();
    int attack = attackDamage * attackSpeed;

    if(attack<hero.getArmor()){
        reducedDamage=hero.getArmor()-attack;

    }
    else{
        reducedDamage=attack-hero.getArmor();

    }
    currentHeroHealth=hero.getHealthPoints()-reducedDamage;
    hero.setHealthPoints(currentHeroHealth);
    return currentHeroHealth;

}




public int attack(Monster monster) { // this method from hero class
    System.out.println("You attacked to monster!");


    int currentMonsterHealth=monster.getHealthPoints()-HitPoints;
    if(currentMonsterHealth==0){
        System.out.println("You defeated the monster"+monster.getName());
        monster.setHealthPoints(0);
    }
    else {
        monster.setHealthPoints(currentMonsterHealth);

    }
    return currentMonsterHealth;
}
```

Comment: I think that you are overthinking it. I would modify the Character class' attack to be ``attack(Character character)`` rather than object, and I'd override the methods with the same parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for Java generics. This is an example:

### Character class

```
public abstract class Charachter<T> {
    public abstract int attack(T object);
}
```

You declare the class `Character` to be parametrized with a parameter of type `T`.

### Monster class

```
public class Monster extends Character<Hero> {
    @Override
    public int attack(Hero object) {
        //your implementation
    }
}
```

You declare that your `Monster` class extends the base class with a type `Hero`, so that the parameter will be `Hero`.

### Hero class

```
public class Hero extends Character<Monster> {
    @Override
    public int attack(Monster object) {
        //your implementation
    }
}
```

You declare that your `Hero` class extends the base class with type `Monster`, so that the type of your overridden method will be `Monster`.

Answer (score 0):

If the base method has an `Object` parameter, the overritten method also needs to have an `Object` parameter. While subclasses can override methods with more general parameters, more specialized parameters are not allowed.

However, you can use `instanceof` in order to decide what method to call:

```java
public int attack(Object object){
    if(object instanceof Hero){
        return attack((Hero)object);
    }
    if(object instanceof Monster){
        return attack((Monster)object);
    }
    //Do whatever you want to do if the object is neither a hero nor a monster
}
```